# emacs org mode: how do i refer to the current row number?

Tags: org-mode

i would like to use the current row number of my org table in cell calculations, either in relation to the table as a whole or in relation to an hline.

if i have the following table:

```
|---+---+---|
| x | y | z |
|---+---+---|
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
|---+---+---|
#+TBLFM: @II..@III$1=2::$2=4::$3=$1*$2
```

how do I change it so that the in the y column each cell is equal to its table row number, as shown if you turn on grid mode in org? the resulting table would look like:

```
|---+----+----|
| x |  y |  z |
|---+----+----|
| 2 |  2 |  4 |
| 2 |  3 |  6 |
| 2 |  4 |  8 |
| 2 |  5 | 10 |
| 2 |  6 | 12 |
| 2 |  7 | 14 |
| 2 |  8 | 16 |
| 2 |  9 | 18 |
| 2 | 10 | 20 |
|---+----+----|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defmath passIndex (x)
  x
)
```

Number rows:

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
#+TBLFM: $1=passIndex(@#)
```

Number columns:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
#+TBLFM: @1=passIndex($#)
```

Number rows with header row:

```
| header |
|--------|
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
|      5 |
#+TBLFM: $1=passIndex(@#)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I've been searching for this for some time.

Comment: why are we doing the pass index function, and not just @# and $#?

Comment: I am accustomed to using the row and column org variables in custom calc functions. But I see now that you can use them directly, as you have pointed out.